# How to change the name of a VC++ project?

Tags: visual-c++

i am building a VC++ project named FileOut , when i build the application i get an exe named FileOut.exe. Is there any way that i get an exe with different name like File.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this , Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> output file , change the name  from   $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe to your name like $(OutDir)\YourName.exe

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project and choose Properties.

Find the Linker section, and edit the Output File setting as you wish.